# Git, not staged changes of some Windows files on Mac (or Ubuntu)

Tags: git, macos, ubuntu

I failed to update youcompleteme by BundleUpdate!

I found that it may be the OmniSharpServer repo caused the problem.

```
~/nuts/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/OmniSharpServer/cecil (master)$ git st
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   LICENSE.md
    modified:   Mono.Cecil.csproj
    modified:   Mono.Cecil.settings
    modified:   Mono.Cecil.sln

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

In vim I found the modified files with fileformat=dos, and there are no differences shown by "git dt LICENSE.md" with difftool vimdiff.

I tried dos2uinx and unix2dos, but no help to discard those changes.

"git co -- ." can not discard those changes.

"git reset --hard" can not discard those changes.

So how to discard those changes?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard`

LICENSE.md though ought to have changes, to the best of my knowledge. Indeed in my experience the *difftool*s only come up if you do have differences, if you don't they are not even launched. Are you sure you're just not noticing them?